# Error when importing a CSV file into Woocommerce

Tags: wordpress, csv, import, woocommerce, crash

I would like to import a CSV file into the Woocommerce shop. For this I have the plugin "Woocommerce CSV import" installed and with a test CSV file tried, which also worked. Now I have a nearly 42MB large CSV file. In the table, as seen in the picture, the individual entries have been divided with vertical separators. When trying to import the CSV file, Wordpress crashes at 1% and Firefox returns the message "The page is no longer reachable".

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/newtS.png)

Now I have thought that it might be necessary to convert the table. In which format would I have to convert the table without changing anything by hand? Is the table in UTF-8 format?

Comment: What's the max upload size?

Comment: I'm not sure. Does the maximum uploade size refer to Woocommerce or the CSV plugin? Should not it really matter how big the CSV file is?

Comment: Update: I have integrated the CSV via JTL. No additional plug-in is required. Many thanks for the answer. The question applies to me as answered. Thanks.